# Does stored procedure execute when ASP.NET application which called it has timed out?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, timeout

I've  a ASP.NET web application which calls a long running stored procedure,
and times out in between, in this scenario will the stored procedure execute. Yes i'm aware that we can increase the timeout duration, but i'm doubtful about the execution of stored procedure

Comment: Can you be clearer about what times out?  Does the SQLConnection or the ASP.Net request time out?

Comment: If the asp request is timing out, SP should continue the execution, because DBMS is separate entity from IIS and once the execution has started it will continue executing the stored procedure, though I am not so sure about it

Comment: I think if you don't care about the results of the SP then just run it on another thread and return.

Comment: Its the ASP.NET application which times out

Answer (score 0):

first of all check your stored procedure execute it, if it shows proper result that means it executed successfully. then increase timeout duration
Stored procedure takes time to show result depends upon the data, your logic, etc. but finally it definitely show result.

on application timeout

in web.config

```
<location path="something.aspx">
        <system.web>
                <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90"/>
        </system.web>
</location>
```

you can change executionTimeout according to your need

for more information 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx

Comment: Yes, i've executed the stored procedure directly from sql server, it does executes and returns the proper result. I was doubtful about whether it will execute when a call is given from ASP.NET application, and that application times out, what will happen in this case, will the SP continue its execution or even it will stop